# Importing existing sbt project to IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I had the project that I was working on using intellJ. A while back I deleted the project; and now I want to work on the project again. However, I cannot import a project into Intellj 2017.2.6, after cloning the project. I  have also installed the latest Scala plug-in.

Here is the log:

```
[info] Loading settings from plugins.sbt,scaffold.sbt ...
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Users\Lisa\repositories\Centuries\project
[info] Loading settings from build.sbt ...
[info] Set current project to play-java-starter-example (in build file:/C:/Users/Lisa/repositories/Centuries/)
[info] sbt server started at local:sbt-server-32d2c5673d7428dec3ce
[play-java-starter-example] $
[info] Defining Global / sbtStructureOptions, Global / sbtStructureOutputFile, shellPrompt
[info] The new values will be used by no settings or tasks.
[info] Reapplying settings...
[info] Set current project to play-java-starter-example (in build file:/C:/Users/Lisa/repositories/Centuries/)
[info] Applying State transformations org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks from C:/Users/Lisa/.IntelliJIdea2017.2/config/plugins/Scala/launcher/sbt-structure-1.1.jar
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks$
[error]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[error]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
[error]     at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.ModuleUtilities$.getObject(ModuleUtilities.scala:20)
[error]     at sbt.BasicCommands$.$anonfun$call$5(BasicCommands.scala:203)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$map$1(TraversableLike.scala:234)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
[error]     at scala.collection.TraversableLike.map$(TraversableLike.scala:227)
[error]     at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:295)
[error]     at sbt.BasicCommands$.$anonfun$call$2(BasicCommands.scala:203)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$4(Command.scala:134)
[error]     at sbt.Command$.$anonfun$applyEffect$2(Command.scala:130)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.processCommand(MainLoop.scala:153)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$2(MainLoop.scala:136)
[error]     at sbt.State$$anon$1.runCmd$1(State.scala:242)
[error]     at sbt.State$$anon$1.process(State.scala:248)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$next$1(MainLoop.scala:136)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.next(MainLoop.scala:136)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.run(MainLoop.scala:129)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1(MainLoop.scala:107)
[error]     at sbt.io.Using.apply(Using.scala:22)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:101)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:57)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:42)
[error]     at sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:34)
[error]     at sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:113)
[error]     at sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:76)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:128)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
[error] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jetbrains.sbt.CreateTasks$
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
[info] shutting down server
[INFO] [02/02/2018 08:48:16.063] [Thread-3] [CoordinatedShutdown(akka://sbt-web)] Starting coordinated shutdown from JVM shutdown hook
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=384M; support was removed in 8.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your project is using sbt 1.1, and there is a bug that prevents importing in IntelliJ 2017.2. Upgrading to IntelliJ/Scala 2017.3.11 or later should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following steps and see if it solves your problem:

1. **Restart/Close the IntellJ**: can you do the `sbt clean compile` with no problem? If so, thats the IntellJ issue, so first close/restart the IntellJ.
2. **Delete the .idea file**: Ok first of all copy/paste your folder to a new path. In the new folder delete the `.idea` file (generated file used by Intellj).
3. **Import the project**: In intellJ go to `File > open` and open the project in the new folder and choose the 'auto import'. Make sure that your scala and sbt version is the same as build.sbt.
4. **Invalidate the Cach**e: Go to `File > Invalidate Cache / Restarts`. This is also solves my problem specially when I'm working in a Gradle based project.